# postgresql error: column "xx" does not exist of equal operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to find some specific rows with equal operator:

```
select * 
from noteevents
where DESCRIPTION = "Report"
order by charttime
limit 100
;
```

But I don't know it gives me an error which is

```
ERROR:  column "Report" does not exist
LINE 3: where DESCRIPTION = "Report"
                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "Report" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 46
```

And the noteevents structure is as follow:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes instead?

Comment: No, the problem is double quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes for string constants:

```
select * 
from noteevents
where DESCRIPTION = 'Report'
order by charttime
limit 100;
```

Double quotes are for escaping the names of columns and tables.